# How do you cancel ongoing client request when using Autorest with typescript?

Tags: typescript, autorest

Is there a way to abort an ongoing client request when using Autorest with typescript?

I noticed the `ServiceClient` object has the ability to specify `RequestPrepareOptions`, but I'm unclear how to pass the request options to the outgoing request method. Or perhaps there's another means to do the cancelation?

Comment: Maybe you could add some code to examplify what you would like to do, and what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use the browser [abortController mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). You have to create an abort signal:

> The **AbortController** interface represents a controller object that allows you to abort one or more Web requests as and when desired.
>
> ```
> var controller = new AbortController();
> var signal = controller.signal;
> ```
>
> ...

Then pass it in [`OperationArguments.options.abortSignal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/core-http/requestoptionsbase?view=azure-node-latest#abortSignal) when calling

```
function sendOperationRequest<T>(operationArguments: OperationArguments, operationSpec: OperationSpec)
```

Then call `abort`on then abortController :

```
abortBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  controller.abort();
  console.log('Download aborted');
});
```

...and the promise returned by `sendOperationRequest` shall be rejected with an `abortError`.

See provided javascript example : https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/abort-api/

Note: The feature is marked *experimental*, so it may not be supported by all browsers.